# binary predicate to square list and sublists in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am new to prolog and was trying to create a binary predicate which will give
 a list in which all numbers are squared, including those in sublists.
    e.g.

```
?-dcountSublists([a,[[3]],b,4,c(5),4],C).
  C=[a,[[9]],b,c(5),16]
```

Can anyone guide me how i can do this. 
Thank You. Answer with a snippet is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily achieved using recursion in Prolog. Remember that everything in Prolog is either a variable, or a term (atoms are just 0-arity terms), so a *term* like the following:

```
[a,[[3]],b,4,c(5),4]
```

...is easily deconstructed (also note that the list syntax `[..]` is sugar for the binary predicate [`./2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=./2)). Prolog offers a range of predicates to test for particular *types* of terms as well, such as numbers, strings, or compound terms (such as [`compound/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.5%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/typetest.html%27%29%29)).

To build the predicate you're after, I recommend writing it using several predicates like this:

```
dcountSublists(In, Out) :-
  % analyze type of In
  % based on type, either: 
  %   1. split term into subterms for recursive processing
  %   2. term cannot be split; either replace it, or pass it through
```

Here's an example to get you started which does the hard bit. The following recognizes compound terms and breaks them apart with the term de/constructor [`=../2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28=..%29/2):

```
dcountSublists(In, Out) :-
  % test if In has type compound term
  compound(In),
  % cut to exclude backtracking to other cases below this predicate
  !, 
  % deconstruct In into functor and an argument list
  In =.. [Func|Args],
  % apply dcountSublists/2 to every argument, building new args
  maplist(dcountSublists, Args, NewArgs),
  % re-construct In using the new arguments
  Out =.. [Func|NewArgs].

dcountSublists(In, Out) :-
  % test if In has type atom
  atom(In), !, 
  % pass it through
  Out = In.
```

Testing:

```
?- dcountSublists([a,[[e]],b,a,c(s),a], L).
L = [a, [[e]], b, a, c(s), a].
```

Note that this fails if the input term has numbers, because it doesn't have a predicate to recognize and deal with them. I'll leave this up to you.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

SWI-Prolog has the predicate [maplist/[2-5]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.2%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/apply.html%27%29%29) which allows you to map a predicate over some lists.
Using that, you only have to make a predicate that will square a number or the numbers in a list and leave everything else the same. The predicates number/1, is_list/1 are true if their argument is a number or a list.

Therefore:

```
    square(N,NN):-
            integer(N),
            NN is N*N.

    square(L,LL):-
            is_list(L),
            dcountSublists(square,L,LL).

    square(Other,Other):-
            \+ number(Other),
            \+ is_list(Other).

    dcountSublists(L,LSquared):-
            maplist(square,L,LSquared).
```

with the negation in the final predicate we avoid multiple (wrong) solutions:
for example `dcountSublists([2],X)` would return `X=[4]` and `X=[2]` otherwise.
This could be avoided if we used an if-then-else structure for square `or once/1` to call `square/2`.

If this is homework maybe you should not use maplist since (probably) the aim of the exercise is to learn how to build a recursive function; in any case, I would suggest to try and write an equivalent predicate without maplist.